# parsing Salesforce bulk api data into chunks to process

Tags: javascript, node.js, salesforce-lightning

I have this below code where i am getting results from Bulk APi query job which huge in number (60,000 to 80,000) records. I am converting it to JSON and will be inserting into a database. Can anyone suggest best way to handle huge amount of data and how to process it in chunks.

```
request.get( options, function ( error, response, body ) {
        if ( error )
        {

        } else
        {
            csvJson()
                .fromString( response.body )
                .then( ( jsonObj ) => {
                    var a = JSON.stringify( jsonObj );
                } )
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Large data, chunks, these are the keywords that hint the use of generators. You should definitely use a generator. But before that the API must support pagination as well, otherwise the generators may be useless as well

Comment: Which kind of generator u r recommending?

Comment: I dunno what language or framework you are talking about but native REST Salesforce API can render up to 2K records by request, which means for 80K you have to make 40 requests, in each request you will get the next query result id like pagination.

Btw salesforce is not designed to make a lot of query, at least freely, they sell 10K request for 25$ monthly, and even in pro version you only get 100K request / 24h.

Meaning is you have to make some kind of cache control on your own side depending on what you want to do ofc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
async function* readApi() {
  let page = 1;
  while (page != null) {
    const r = await fetch(`http://target-api.com/stuff?page=${page}`)
    const d = await r.json()
    page = yield d
  }
}

const it = readApi()

it.next() // Init fn with first next call it will get the first page
it.next(2) // Gets the second page, process the data and go to next call
// ..
// ..
it.next(null) // When you are done with getting data call with null
```